# Filedialogue error in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

Question about Tkinter :

I want to create a browse along with a text display which will display the file that I pick from the browse button. Following is my code :

#### Edit 1.

```
button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='Browse and open filename - then manually upload it', command=self.askopenfilename).pack(**button_opt)

    self.file_opt = options = {}        
    options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
    options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
    options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.txt'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['title'] = 'Browse'

    self.dir_opt = options = {}
    options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
    options['mustexist'] = False
    options['parent'] = root
    options['title'] = 'Browse'

    image = Image.open("/home/kuber/Downloads/godata/images/header.png")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = Label(image=photo)
    label.image = photo # keep a reference!
    label.place(width=768, height=576)
    label.pack(side = TOP)

    self.centerWindow()
    self.master.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
    #Tkinter.Button(self, text='upload file', command=self.Fname).pack(**button_opt)    
    self.file_name = Text(self, width=39, height=1, wrap=WORD)

def Fname(self):
    self.file_name = Text(self, width=39, height=1, wrap=WORD)
        self.file_name.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W)

def askopenfilename(self):

   # get filename
     filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)

   # open file on your own
     if filename:
     with open(self.filename, 'r') as inp_file:
        print "1"
        self.file_name.delete(0.0, END)
        self.file_name.insert(0.0, inp_file.read())
            #return open(filename, 'r')
```

As I press the button for Browse and open file. I expect to go from `askopenfilename` function to the text widget. But I get the error :

`AttributeError: TkFileDialogExample instance has no attribute 'filename'`

Also when I include self.file_name.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W) outside Fname, Tkinter hangs.

Comment: Are you just wanting to display text files? For that yo would use a `Text` widget. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm and http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html

Answer (score 1):

When you see a python error like `X instance has no attribute 'filename', it means exactly what it says. The root cause is usually one of two things:

- X is the object you intended to use, and it indeed does not have that attributev(maybe you misspelled it, o forgot to define it), or
- You told the program to use X, but X is not what you think it s (ie: you think it refers to an object of a particular type but it's a string or number or some other class.

So, ask yourself, "why doesn't TkFileDialogExample have this attribute? Did you define it to have that attribute? Where and when? Did you misspell it? Or, is your code supposed to get the attribute from some other object?

In other words, your code is using `self.filename`: is `self` what you think it is?